# Change parameters of a query by user input (react)

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to add an input field where a user can type a number and that number would get passed on as a parameter. In the code below I can hard code per_page (in this case 3) which would return 3 images from the Unsplash API.

```
onSearchSubmit = async (term) => {
        const response = await unsplash.get('/search/photos', {
            params: {
                query: term,
                per_page: 3,
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state that stores the value for the user for an input field.

You would need to store state like this:

```
  const inputForm = () =>{
    const [value, setValue] = useState(1)
    
    return (
// Code for your form
    <input 
    onChange={(e)=>{
    setValue(e.target.value)
    }}
    value={value}
    />
    )

//End your form 
    
    }
```

Make sure onClick you run your onSearchSubmit function with the value as an argument.

Then your function can simply be:

```
onSearchSubmit = async (term, value) => {
        const response = await unsplash.get('/search/photos', {
            params: {
                query: term,
                per_page: value,
            },
        });
```

Comment: I sort of understand the concept, here is a link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-snow-hhw4p?file=/src/api/unsplash.js . The params is defined in components folder in App.js. How would you implement it?